# How to delete child entity in many to many relationship (Spring jpa rest app) without deleting the parent?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I've a many to many relationship between experts and tags. I'd like to allow user to delete one tag that expert contains without delete the whole expert entity. Right now always that I delete one tagIi get all expert also deleted.

**My spring jpa app controler method to delete tag by id:**

```
 @DeleteMapping("/tags/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteTagById(@PathVariable Long id){
        log.debug("REST request to delete a tag by Id{} ", id);
        return tagService.deleteById(id);
    }
```

**my tag model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tags")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="tags", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<Expert> experts = new ArrayList<>();

    public Tag() {
    } //getters and setters
```

**my expert model:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="experts")
public class Expert {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String dni;
    private String address;
    private String mail;
    private String phone;
    private String linkedln;
    private String state;
    private String rating;
    private String availability;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "experts_tags",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="tags_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="experts_id", referencedColumnName = "id")}
    )
    private List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>();


    public Expert() {
    } //getters and setters
```

**What Ive tried So FAR:**

This method effectively deletes the tag but also the expert:

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteTag(Long id) {
        Tag tag=this.manager.find(Tag.class,id);
        this.manager.remove(tag);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
```

This method I tried to avoid this returns 500 error:

```
public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteTagById(Long id) {
        Expert expert = (Expert) manager.createQuery("SELECT  Expert from Tag u where u.id = :id");

        for(Tag tag : expert.getTags()){
            if (tag.getId() == id){
                expert.getTags().remove(tag);
                manager.persist(expert);
            }
        }
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();

    }
}

    }
```

Anyone could help me? I appreciate any advise :) Thank you!

Comment: There is no property called `Expert` in `Tag`

Answer (score -2):

That's because you defined that all actions should cascade to experts:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="tags", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
private List<Expert> experts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Instead of using `ALL`, you should list what you actually want to cascade.